# Drop down menu for Plotly graph

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly, visualization

Here is my dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date":["2020-01-27","2020-02-27","2020-03-27","2020-04-27", "2020-05-27", "2020-06-27", "2020-07-27",
                          "2020-01-27","2020-02-27","2020-03-27","2020-04-27", "2020-05-27", "2020-06-27", "2020-07-27"],
                   "A_item":[2, 8, 0, 1, 8, 10, 4, 7, 2, 15, 5, 12, 10, 7],
                   "B_item":[1, 7, 10, 6, 5, 9, 2, 5, 6, 1, 2, 6, 15, 8],
                   "C_item":[9, 2, 9, 3, 9, 18, 7, 2, 8, 1, 2, 8, 1, 3],
                   "Channel_type":["Chanel_1", "Chanel_1", "Chanel_1", "Chanel_1", "Chanel_1", "Chanel_1", "Chanel_1", 
                                   "Chanel_2", "Chanel_2", "Chanel_2", "Chanel_2", "Chanel_2", "Chanel_2", "Chanel_2"]
                   })
```

I want to plot a group Bar chart with the dropdown filter on the **Channel_type** col. That's what I am trying:

```
trace2 = go.Bar(x=df["Date"], y=df[["B_item"]])
trace3 = go.Bar(x=df["Date"], y=df[["C_item"]])

list_updatemenus = [{'label': 'All',
  'method': 'update',
  'args': [{'visible': [True, True]}, {'title': 'All'}]},
 {'label': 'Chanel_1',
  'method': 'update',
  'args': [{'visible': [True, False]}, {'title': 'Chanel_1'}]},
 {'label': 'Chanel_2',
  'method': 'update',
  'args': [{'visible': [False, True]}, {'title': 'Chanel_2'}]}]


data = [trace1,trace2,trace3]

layout=go.Layout(title='Distribution of Sales by Region',updatemenus=list([dict(buttons= list_updatemenus)]),width=1000,height=800,barmode='group')


fig = go.Figure(data,layout)

fig.show()
```

And not getting the desired output:[Plot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPTRG.png)

As it filters the graph by the **"A_item"**, **"B_item"** and **"C_item"** while I would like to filter it by the **Channel_type** col as mentioned.

So the ideal result would be the below graph, but with the dropdown menu that changes the graph based on Channel_type :

[Plot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17Qa5.png)

I am able to solve the problem with Ipywidgets in the Jupyter notebook, but it’s not really working for my particular task. Here is the code:

```
from plotly import graph_objs as go
import ipywidgets as w
from IPython.display import display

x  = 'Date'
y1 = 'A_item'
y2 = 'B_item'
y3 = 'C_item'

trace1 = {
 'x': df[x],
 'y': df[y1],
 'type': 'bar',
 'name':'A_item'
}

trace2={
 'x': df[x],
 'y': df[y2],
 'type': 'bar',
 'name':'B_item'
}

trace3 = {
 'x': df[x],
 'y': df[y3],
 'type': 'bar',
 'name':'C_item',
 
}

data = [trace1, trace2, trace3]

# Create layout for the plot
layout=dict(
 title='Channels', 
 width=1200, height=700, title_x=0.5,
 paper_bgcolor='#fff',
 plot_bgcolor="#fff",
 xaxis=dict(
     title='Date', 
     type='date', 
     tickformat='%Y-%m-%d',
     gridcolor='rgb(255,255,255)',
     zeroline= False,
 ),
 yaxis=dict(
     title='My Y-axis',
     zeroline= False
         )
     )

fig = go.FigureWidget(data=data, layout=layout)

def update_fig(change):
 aux_df = df[df.Channel_type.isin(change['new'])]
 with fig.batch_update():
     for trace, column in zip(fig.data, [y1, y2, y3]):
         trace.x = aux_df[x]
         trace.y = aux_df[column]

drop = w.Dropdown(options=[
 ('All', ['Chanel_1', 'Chanel_2']),
 ('Chanel_1', ['Chanel_1']),
 ('Chanel_2', ['Chanel_2']),
])
drop.observe(update_fig, names='value')



display(w.VBox([drop, fig]))
```

And here is the output:

[image: Output]

The problem is that I am not able to wrap the VBox into an HTML file and save the dropdown menu. Also, it isn’t working in the Python shell as it is intended for the Jupyter notebook, and I need to share it.

So the ideal result would be to wrap the last figure within the Plotly fig only without the ipywidgets.

Any help be really appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: So it sounds like you want to be able to use a dropdown menu with the same functionality as clicking the individual traces in the legend. Do you want multiple channels to be able to be selected from the dropdown or do you only want one channel at a time?

Comment: Hi Derek the ideal would be : dropdown menu: option1 = channel_1, option2 = channel_2, option3 = both channel_1 and channel_2 thank you!

Comment: And yea exactly the same layout for the remaining part of the graph. Dropdown - is just a filter for a channel_type col. The only thing is that I'd like to have it within the plotly fig() and not with ipython widgets thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most important thing to note is that for `go.Bar`, if you have `n` dates in the `x` parameter and you pass a 2D array of dimension (m, n) to the `y` parameter of `go.Bar`, Plotly understands to create a grouped bar chart with each date n having `m` bars.

For your DataFrame, something like `df[df['Channel_type'] == "Channel_1"][items].T.values` will reshape it as needed. So we can apply this to the `y` field of `args` that we pass the to the buttons we make.

Credit to @vestland for the portion of the code making adjustments to the buttons to make it a dropdown.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = pd.DataFrame({"Date":["2020-01-27","2020-02-27","2020-03-27","2020-04-27", "2020-05-27", "2020-06-27", "2020-07-27",
                          "2020-01-27","2020-02-27","2020-03-27","2020-04-27", "2020-05-27", "2020-06-27", "2020-07-27"],
                   "A_item":[2, 8, 0, 1, 8, 10, 4, 7, 2, 15, 5, 12, 10, 7],
                   "B_item":[1, 7, 10, 6, 5, 9, 2, 5, 6, 1, 2, 6, 15, 8],
                   "C_item":[9, 2, 9, 3, 9, 18, 7, 2, 8, 1, 2, 8, 1, 3],
                   "Channel_type":["Channel_1", "Channel_1", "Channel_1", "Channel_1", "Channel_1", "Channel_1", "Channel_1", 
                                   "Channel_2", "Channel_2", "Channel_2", "Channel_2", "Channel_2", "Channel_2", "Channel_2"]
                   })

fig = go.Figure()

colors = ['#636efa','#ef553b','#00cc96']
items = ["A_item","B_item","C_item"]
for item, color in zip(items, colors):
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
        x=df["Date"], y=df[item], marker_color=color
        ))

# one button for each df column
# slice the DataFrame and apply transpose to reshape it correctly
updatemenu= []
buttons=[]
for channel in df['Channel_type'].unique():
    buttons.append(dict(method='update',
                        label=channel,
                        args=[{
                        'y': df[df['Channel_type'] == channel][items].T.values
                        }])
                  )

## add a button for both channels
buttons.append(dict(
    method='update',
    label='Both Channels',
    args=[{
    'y': df[items].T.values
    }])
)

# some adjustments to the updatemenu
# from code by vestland
updatemenu=[]
your_menu=dict()
updatemenu.append(your_menu)
updatemenu[0]['buttons']=buttons
updatemenu[0]['direction']='down'
updatemenu[0]['showactive']=True

fig.update_layout(updatemenus=updatemenu)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Derek thank you, but that's a bit different from what I was looking for. I want the graph to show all A, B, C items in a grouped bar and just be filtered by the Channel_type col. In your example, we're again filtering by traces that are A, B, C item cols. Thanks!

Comment: Oh I see what you mean now. I will try to fix this, and change the answer

Comment: thanks Derek! Also, I was able to solve this by using the Ipython widgets, but like I said it doesn't fit this particular task as I need to solve it within the Plotly fig(). Thanks!

Comment: Derek, I have edited my initial question and now it includes what I can make with the ipywidgets, but that doesn't suit my task as I need to share and would like the plot and dropdown menus to wrap in the Plotly fig only. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, I've updated my answer. Hopefully it works as you intended this time around!

Comment: Derek - thank you so much! that's exactly what I was looking for) thanks!

Comment: No problem, it was cool figuring this out too!